# How to push objectId to mongodb schema field array of object using findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Everytime I hit api I am getting same error- 
I have tried sending value as parameters also but failed. Any help would be appreciated. When i use `$set` it updates same value everytime the web service is called but it does work but not with `$push`.

MongoError: The field 'songId' must be an array but is of type `objectId` in document

```
 {_id: ObjectId('59709590380026118c22dd61')}
```

---

My Playlist schema code:-

```
var PlaylistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
  name: String,
  coverphoto: { type: String, default: '' },
  userId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  songId: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Song' }],
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

my Song Schema code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var SongSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  audioName:{type:String,default:''},
  title: String,
  // coverphoto: { type: String, default: '' },
  singer: { type: String, default: '' },
  movie: { type: String, default: '' },
  album: { type: String, default: '' },
  lyricist: { type: String, default: '' },
  actors: { type: String, default: '' },
  lyrics: { type: String, default: '' },
  genre: { type: String, default: 'Random' },
  duration: { type: String, default: '' },
  size: { type: String, default: '' },
  userId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  categoryId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category'
  },    
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Song', SongSchema);
```

My Api code

```
/* post api to add song in playlist */
router.post('/addSongToPlaylist', function (req, res, next) {
  Playlist.findOne({ '_id': req.body.playlistId }, function (err, playlist) {      

    if (err) return next(err);

    console.log(playlist)
    console.log("req.body.songId", req.body.songId);
    if (playlist) {
      Playlist.findByIdAndUpdate(
         req.body.playlistId,
          { $push: { "songId": req.body.songId } },
          { new: true },
          function (err, playlistData) {
              if (err) return next(err);
              res.json({ message: 'New Song added successfully', playlist: playlistData, success: true });
          });
    } else if (!Song) {
      res.json({ message: 'Failed to add song', success: false });
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Is the error not descriptive enough? It's actually telling you that `req.body.songId` is a "document" `{_id: ObjectId('59709590380026118c22dd61')}` and frankly if it actually looks like that and logs like that then what you supplied was actually a "string" with the words `ObjectId` in it, which is not correct for transport. Instead your `songId` parameter should simply been the "string value" being `"59709590380026118c22dd61"`. And then there would be no problem as mongoose would cast the type correctly for you.

Comment: Even when i tried to push using get web service and send songId and playlistId as parameter but still it gives the same error                                              GET GET /api/addSongToPlaylist/59709590380026118c22dd61/59705f3b1fe3e01534fc38f7 500 213.755 ms - 1192
MongoError: The field 'songId' must be an array but is of type objectId in document {_id: ObjectId('59709590380026118c22dd61')}

Comment: Because it's a "string" and also in the incorrect format. Read the comment again and try to understand it.

Comment: could you please tell me that how should i send the object Id to the webservice so that i push songId to the songId array of reference object field

Comment: i got the solution. I have just converted the value to string and it worked. Thanks Neil